# CSS table-row:after провести линию

Tags: html, css, display

Подскажите, как можно применить after к table-row в этом коде:

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-row line">
        <div class="table-cell">Поле 1</div>
        <div class="table-cell">Поле 2</div>
        <div class="table-cell">Поле 3</div>
        <div class="table-cell">Поле 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row line">
        <div class="table-cell">Поле 1</div>
        <div class="table-cell">Поле 2</div>
        <div class="table-cell">Поле 3</div>
        <div class="table-cell">Поле 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row line">
        <div class="table-cell">Поле 1</div>
        <div class="table-cell">Поле 2</div>
        <div class="table-cell">Поле 3</div>
        <div class="table-cell">Поле 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.table-row {
    display: table-row;
}
.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 10px 0
}
.line:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    background: #000;
}
```

Comment: Может, так? http://jsfiddle.net/m0Lm740t/  http://jsfiddle.net/k8eb8dsn/

Comment: с border то понятно, но необходимо с помощью :after

Сейчас к примеру сделал дополнительный div между .table и .table-row. Вот только не знаю, можно ли так делать или есть какие то стандарты для некоторых браузеров которые не позволяют помещать ничего между ними.

    <div class="table">
        <div class="line">
            <div class="table-row">
                <div class="table-cell"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

Можно ли выполнить верстку в таком стиле?